# Visual Studio Code Docker Error "The task 'Containers: Logs: node' neither specifies a command nor a dependsOn property"

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I am completely stumped by this. I have a Docker Compose project which otherwise runs fine without errors, the Output Panel of Visual Studio Code defaults to the "Tasks" option in the drop down menu and randomly repeats the following error.

```
Error: the task 'Containers: Logs: node' neither specifies a command nor a dependsOn property. The task will be ignored. Its definition is:
{
    "type": "shell",
    "id": "shell,docker logs --tail 1000 -f 15481a5cec4424532ece76246ba1a83e5922be5b544569363d8c75ef20f3a539,",
    "idRandomizer": 0.9071646986255444,
    "problemMatcher": [],
    "label": "Containers: Logs: node"
}
```

I don't know if it's a problem with my Docker Node image, VSCode or the Docker extension in VSCode. Something appears to be running a "task", and it's not me, called "Containers: Logs: node" which is failing.

Can anyone at least tell me where this task is being run and or how I can go about debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the Docker Extension for Visual Studio Code. I rearranged the panel layout in Visual Studio Code so the Output panel and Docker Extension panel are both visible at the same time. Each time you right click on a Container in the Docker panel and select "View logs" from the drop down menu the error is generated in the Tasks section of the Output Panel.

Nothing to do with my code.